# Trouble with CSS positioning for small screen

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, positioning

I need to add CSS for my webpage to make it better suitable for small screens and phones. My `@media` modification doesn't seem to work. I have to make it look like this:

[image: Protocols Image]

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background: #689;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #689, #245);
  border-radius: 1.25em;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 30px;
   width: 15%;
}
main {
   float: left;
   width: 40em;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  float: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">Protocols</h1>
 
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#top">Top of Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="#email">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="#http">HTTP</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<main>
<p><dfn>Protocols</dfn> (or <dfn>communications protocols</dfn>) are agreed ways for to computers to communicate and exchange information. The Wikipedia page on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol">communications protocols</a> contains much more information than we can cover here.</p>
  
<section id="email">
<h2>Email Protocols</h2>
<p>There are several protocols that make email work:</p>
<ul>
<li><p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p></li>
<li><p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p></li>
<li><p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
<p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p></li>
</ul>
</section>
  
<section id="http">
<h2>HTTP</h2>
<p>The  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web">World Wide Web</a> rests on the protocol <abbr title="Hypertext Transfer Protocol">HTTP</abbr>.</p>
<p>HTTP is a client-server protocol. That means that an HTTP client (like a web browser, also called a &ldquo;user agent&rdquo;) contacts an HTTP server and makes a request. The request is likely a request for a particular web page available on that server. The server will respond with a response: often the contents of the web page that was requested.</p>
  <section id="uses">
  <h3>Uses</h3>
  <p>HTTP is often used to transfer <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr> documents which we generally think of as &ldquo;web pages&rdquo;. HTML contains markup like <code class="html">&lt;em&gt;</code> and <code class="html">&lt;a href="http://example.com/"&gt;</code>.</p>
  <p>Every piece of content available on the web is called a <dfn>resource</dfn> and is available at a URL like <code class="url">http://example.com/somepage.html</code>.</p>
  </section>
</section>
 
</main>
```

Comment: try to change `@media` to `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {..some styles here..}`

Comment: hmm..that didn't work

Comment: Don't vandalise your questions, we'll just revert the changes and if you keep it up a moderator will probably step in and suspend your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
 nav {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
 } 
 main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
 nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
  }

}
```

Comment: the nav menu items are still appearing on top of one another instead of being side to side like in the image I posted

Comment: did you apply this to your css

Comment: did you add this to your html page my code and meta tag ?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: i've checked your source code, you are not adding this media query in your stylesheet , add this bottom of the stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

You should put those into a class too to make it work like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  .some-class {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }

}
```

And use the "some-class" where you want those properties.

Here is what you really want:

**Note**: *press F12 and make page's width smaller than 480px to see in-action*

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background: #689;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #689, #245);
  border-radius: 1.25em;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 30px;
   width: 15%;
}
main {
   float: left;
   width: 40em;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  
  li, ul, nav {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">Protocols</h1>
 
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#top">Top of Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="#email">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="#http">HTTP</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<main>
<p><dfn>Protocols</dfn> (or <dfn>communications protocols</dfn>) are agreed ways for to computers to communicate and exchange information. The Wikipedia page on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol">communications protocols</a> contains much more information than we can cover here.</p>
  
<section id="email">
<h2>Email Protocols</h2>
<p>There are several protocols that make email work:</p>
<ul>
<li><p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p></li>
<li><p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p></li>
<li><p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
<p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p></li>
</ul>
</section>
  
<section id="http">
<h2>HTTP</h2>
<p>The  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web">World Wide Web</a> rests on the protocol <abbr title="Hypertext Transfer Protocol">HTTP</abbr>.</p>
<p>HTTP is a client-server protocol. That means that an HTTP client (like a web browser, also called a &ldquo;user agent&rdquo;) contacts an HTTP server and makes a request. The request is likely a request for a particular web page available on that server. The server will respond with a response: often the contents of the web page that was requested.</p>
  <section id="uses">
  <h3>Uses</h3>
  <p>HTTP is often used to transfer <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr> documents which we generally think of as &ldquo;web pages&rdquo;. HTML contains markup like <code class="html">&lt;em&gt;</code> and <code class="html">&lt;a href="http://example.com/"&gt;</code>.</p>
  <p>Every piece of content available on the web is called a <dfn>resource</dfn> and is available at a URL like <code class="url">http://example.com/somepage.html</code>.</p>
  </section>
</section>
 
</main>
```

Comment: well instead of class i tried selecting the nav section and the main. neither way worked.

Comment: well instead of class i tried selecting the nav section and the nav menu now goes on top of the main section but each menu item is still stacked on top of each other instead of being side to side like in the picture i posted

Comment: @JohnnySack updated, please check and inform me to update again if not solved

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can not open link from office. However, If I understand your problem correctly then you basically need to make your page appear nicely for smaller viewpots.

**Please modify your @media to following:**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  nav{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  main {
   float: left;
   width: auto;
  }
}
```

**Couple of suggestions:** 
- It is recommended to use max-width to 640px to get better views. 
- Instead of width assigned to main element you can use max-width:40em and width as 100% then you dont need to overwrite for other viewports.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the nav menu items are still appearing on top of one another instead of being side to side like in the image I posted

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background: #689;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #689, #245);
  border-radius: 1.25em;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 30px;
   width: 15%;
}
main {
   float: left;
   width: 40em;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
 nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
 }
 main {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
 }

}
```

```html
<h1 id="top">Protocols</h1>
 
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#top">Top of Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="#email">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="#http">HTTP</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<main>
<p><dfn>Protocols</dfn> (or <dfn>communications protocols</dfn>) are agreed ways for to computers to communicate and exchange information. The Wikipedia page on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol">communications protocols</a> contains much more information than we can cover here.</p>
  
<section id="email">
<h2>Email Protocols</h2>
<p>There are several protocols that make email work:</p>
<ul>
<li><p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p></li>
<li><p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p></li>
<li><p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
<p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p></li>
</ul>
</section>
  
<section id="http">
<h2>HTTP</h2>
<p>The  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web">World Wide Web</a> rests on the protocol <abbr title="Hypertext Transfer Protocol">HTTP</abbr>.</p>
<p>HTTP is a client-server protocol. That means that an HTTP client (like a web browser, also called a &ldquo;user agent&rdquo;) contacts an HTTP server and makes a request. The request is likely a request for a particular web page available on that server. The server will respond with a response: often the contents of the web page that was requested.</p>
  <section id="uses">
  <h3>Uses</h3>
  <p>HTTP is often used to transfer <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr> documents which we generally think of as &ldquo;web pages&rdquo;. HTML contains markup like <code class="html">&lt;em&gt;</code> and <code class="html">&lt;a href="http://example.com/"&gt;</code>.</p>
  <p>Every piece of content available on the web is called a <dfn>resource</dfn> and is available at a URL like <code class="url">http://example.com/somepage.html</code>.</p>
  </section>
</section>
 
</main>
```